# Infinite redirect loop with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework

I'm using Zend Framework (not full version, just some components), but I'm having a little problem. I didn't develop the software that I'll give support. When I tried to install, the first page is redirecting until it breaks my server: `http://localhost/software/manager/index/index/index/index/index/index/index/index/index/index/index/index/index/index/index/index/index/index/index/index`...

Well I looked at all the code and can't figure out what's wrong. Here's my code:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css)$ bootstrapClass.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_flag register_globals off
php_value session.auto_start 0
Options -Indexes
```

http://pastebin.com/DTHrWJYn

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the line

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Url Rewriting works this way. After the url got rewritten, the rules are applied again.

To avoid this, use a `RewriteCond`, for example whether the file does not exist:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Comment: sorry for the late response, but I wasn't around by any technology devices for some days (yeah I didn't know how too). well... actually it didn't work or didn't understand (I guess I didn't understood). I tried:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
and
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]`

but I'm still having the same results. thank once again.